# A little help to better understand JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables from where I substract data, and to get most of the data I have a query that works pretty good, but I can't get a specific row and that's where I need some help.

Table 1:

```
EquipmentID  | EquipmentName | EquipmentTypeID
15           | Tesla         | 68
16           | Colombus      | 93
```

Table 2:

```
EquipmentTypeID | DisplayName      | 
68              | Electrical Device|
93              | GPS Device       |
```

Table 3:

```
EquipmentID  | IPAddress  |
15           | 192.168.1.1|  
16           | 192.168.0.1|
```

So far the data I get is the following using the folowing SQL Syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.IPAddress,
t2.EquipmentID
FROM Table3 t1
JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.EquipmentID = t2.EquipmentID
WHERE IPAddress LIKE '%192%'
```

The result I get looks like

```
IPAddress  | EquipmentID |
192.168.1.1| 15          |
192.168.0.1| 16          |
```

However when I do a JOIN like the followiing then the result is just messed up

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.IPAddress,
t2.EquipmentID,
t3.EquipmentTypeID,
t4.DisplayName
FROM Table3 t1
JOIN Table1 t2 ON t2.EquipmentID = t1.EquipmentID
JOIN Table2 t3 ON t3.EquipmentTypeID = t1.EquipmentTypeID
JOIN Table2 t4 ON t3.EquipmentTypeID = t1.EquipmentTypeID
WHERE IPAddress LIKE '%192'
```

But now the result I get is the following:

```
IPAddress  | EquipmentID |EquipmentTypeID| DisplayName     |
192.168.1.1| 15          |68             | ElectricalDevice|
192.168.1.1| 15          |93             | GPS Device      |
192.168.0.1| 16          |68             | ElectricalDevice|
192.168.0.1| 16          |93             | GPS Device      |
```

Any ideas on how to get the right display name for the corresponding IPAddress and EquipmentID?

If you need more clarification please let me know. Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Why do you join table2 two times? Is it justified in any way? Also, with LIKE '%192' you would not get the result you showed us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining Table2 twice and on the wrong id:

```
JOIN Table2 t3 ON t3.EquipmentTypeID = t1.EquipmentTypeID
JOIN Table2 t4 ON t3.EquipmentTypeID = t1.EquipmentTypeID
```

try this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t3.IPAddress,
t2.EquipmentID,
t3.EquipmentTypeID,
t2.DisplayName
FROM Table3 t3
JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.EquipmentID = t3.EquipmentID
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.EquipmentTypeID = t3.EquipmentTypeID
WHERE IPAddress LIKE '%192'
```

Note: I changed the names of joined tables because it was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
t3.IPAddress,
t3.EquipmentID,
t2.EquipmentTypeID,
t2.DisplayName
FROM Table3 t3
JOIN Table1 t1 ON t3.EquipmentID = t1.EquipmentID
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.EquipmentTypeID = t1.EquipmentTypeID
WHERE IPAddress LIKE '%192.%'
GROUP BY
t3.IPAddress,
t3.EquipmentID,
t2.EquipmentTypeID,
t2.DisplayName
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) it worked, when i have multiple correct answers dont really know what to choose :) thanks a lot :)

Comment: The answer you used in code is an obvious choice :) Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are joining Table2 twice and on the wrong id:

I think you should `JOIN` **T3** to **T1** and then JOIN **T1** to **T2**.

**Like this :**

```
select * from T3
Join T1 on T3.EquipmentID = T1.EquipmentID
Join T2 on T2.EquipmentTypeID = T1.EquipmentTypeID 
WHERE T3.IPAddress LIKE '%192'
```